# Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range, return array.count + 1

Tags: swift, uitableview, return, tableview

I have a tableview with at all times one cell. If there is data to download from Firebase it will put it in an array called posts. When there's for example, two "in my case" servers that the user will download, it will only display one cell instead of two. I thought I could fix this by changing `return posts.count` to `return posts.count + 1` because of the one cell that will be shown at all times. But if I use `return posts.count + 1` I will get a

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

error on line `let post = posts[indexPath.row]`. I have read about this error, but I can't seem to fix it.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if posts.count == 0 {
            self.tableView.setEmptyMessage("No Servers uploaded!")
            return 1
        } else {
            self.tableView.restore()
            return posts.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileCell", for: indexPath) as! ProfileCellTableViewCell

            cell.delegate = self
            return cell
        }else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellMYposts

            cell.Map_image.image = nil
            let post = posts[indexPath.row]
            cell.post = post
            cell.delegate = self

            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of mixing with the `count` property, add an entry to your `posts` array with the content "No Servers uploaded!" when the firebase request has returned an empty result set. That way you don't need any hackish solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some piece of data in `posts[0]`, you are never actually displaying it. For indexPath.row = 0, you are displaying a profile cell, and then you start displaying the data from posts[1] and on. Change your problem line to:
`let post = posts[indexPath.row - 1]`